# Stored Procedure didn't execute all the data

Tags: php, sql-server, flutter

I got a problem while executing my stored procedure in web service that I create in PHP language. If I execute the SP below directly in SQL Server Management Studio, it works perfectly. But when I execute the SP from my web service with PHP, it only executes some of the data in the looping I made in SP.

I got a service table as a master room data. In that SP below, I would like to check is the room available in a date range that I input to stored procedure one by one.

For example, I got 6 rooms in service table, and I want to check it one by one in looping with cursor. When I execute the SP in web service, it only execute 4 rooms in looping, but if I execute the SP in management studio directly, it works perfectly.

Can somebody help me to solve this problem?

Thank you.

```
Create Procedure GetAvailableRoom
    @Date1 Datetime,
    @Date2 Datetime,
    @UserID Varchar(15)
AS
Begin
    
    Delete From Room_Availability Where UserID = @UserID 
    
    Declare @KL Varchar(50)

    Declare Cursor_RA Cursor For SELECT Service_Code FROM Services Where Status = 'ROOM' Order By Service_Code

    Open Cursor_RA

    Fetch Next From Cursor_RA Into @KL

    While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
        Begin
            print @KL
            
            Declare @MyDate DateTime
            Set @MyDate = @Date1

            Declare @Diff Int
            Set @Diff = DateDiff(Day, @Date1, @Date2)

            Declare @Counter Int
            Set @Counter = 0

            print @MyDate
            print @Diff
            print @Counter

            While (@Counter <= @Diff)
                Begin
                    Print 'My Date is ' + Convert(Varchar, format(@MyDate,'yyyy-MM-dd'))

                    if exists(SELECT @KL, format(@MyDate,'yyyy-MM-dd 00:0:00'), Customers.Name + ' | ' + Customers.HP, @UserID
                                FROM Reservation INNER JOIN Reservation_Details ON Reservation.Reservation_Code = Reservation_Details.Reservation_Code 
                                                INNER JOIN Customers ON Reservation.Customer_ID = Customers.Customer_ID 
                                WHERE Reservation_Details.Kode_Service = @KL AND 
                                        Reservation_Details.Checkin <= format(@MyDate,'yyyy-MM-dd 23:59:59') AND 
                                        Reservation_Details.Checkout >= format(@MyDate,'yyyy-MM-dd 00:0:00'))
                        Begin
                            print 'exists'

                            Insert Into Room_Availability (Service_Code,Service_Date,Customer,UserID)
                            SELECT @KL, format(@MyDate,'yyyy-MM-dd 00:0:00'), Customers.Name + ' | ' + Customers.HP, @UserID 
                            FROM Reservation INNER JOIN Reservation_Details ON Reservation.Reservation_Code = Reservation_Details.Reservation_Code 
                                            INNER JOIN Customers ON Reservation.Customer_ID = Customers.Customer_ID 
                            WHERE Reservation_Details.Service_Code = @KL AND 
                                    Reservation_Details.Checkin <= format(@MyDate,'yyyy-MM-dd 23:59:59') AND 
                                    Reservation_Details.Checkout >= format(@MyDate,'yyyy-MM-dd 00:0:00')
                        End
                    Else
                        Begin
                            print 'not exists'

                            Insert Into Room_Availability (Service_Code,Service_Date,Customer,UserID)
                            Values(@KL, format(@MyDate,'yyyy-MM-dd 00:0:00'), 'EMPTY', @UserID)
                        End

                    Set @MyDate = dateadd(dd,1,@MyDate)
                    Set @Counter = @Counter + 1
                End
            
            Fetch Next From Cursor_RA Into @KL
        End

    Close Cursor_RA
    Deallocate Cursor_RA
End
```

This is the web service code.

```
<?php

include 'settings.php';

ini_set('mssql.connect_timeout',15);
$sqlconn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionOptions);
if ($sqlconn === false)
    die(FormatErrors(sqlsrv_errors()));

$tsql = "GetAvailableRoom '" . $_POST['Date1'] . "','" . $_POST['Date2'] . "','" . $_POST['UserID'] . "'";
//echo $tsql;

$cursorType = array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_DYNAMIC);
$getexec = sqlsrv_query($sqlconn, $tsql, null, $cursorType);

if ($getexec === false)
    die(FormatErrors(sqlsrv_errors()));

sqlsrv_free_stmt($getexec);
sqlsrv_close($sqlconn);
```

Comment: Add `SET NOCOUNT ON;` as the first line in the proc body.

Comment: I have added set nocount on to my sp, before alter and after alter, still doesn't work..

Comment: Incidentally, by catting request field values into your query you are wide open for SQL injection attacks. Please change your calling logic to use parameterized queries (or the sqlserv equivalent, if that's not what it's called) before this goes on any server where anyone besides you can get at it.

Comment: @HeriKwok, the `SET NOCOUNT ON;` should be after the `AS` in the proc body.

Comment: After SET NOCOUNT ON; remove all `print` statements, or protect behind an `IF` so PHP doesn't see the debug messages before the completion of the procedure.